# How to access FlexLexer's input function without deriving from yyFlexLexer?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a simple compiler for a simple C like language. To do that I would like to use Flex and Bison but use them both in the context of modern C++
Right now my setup consists of a main.cpp which just instantiates the scanner and parser and starts parsing

```
// some includes here

#include <FlexLexer.h>
#include "parser.tab.hh"

FlexLexer* scanner;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    yy::parser p;
    scanner = new yyFlexLexer;
    // boilerplate
    if (!p()) std::cout << "No errors detected\n";
}
```

scanner.l

```
%option c++ noyywrap

D           [0-9]
L           [a-zA-Z_]
H           [a-fA-F0-9]
E           [Ee][+-]?{D}+
FS          (f|F|l|L)
IS          (u|U|l|L)*

%{
// Several includes

#include "parser.tab.hh"

using token = yy::parser::token;

void count();
void comment();
int check_type();
void add_symbol(void);

void yyerror(const char *);
extern std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> symbol_table;
extern FlexLexer* scanner;
%}
%%
"/*"            { comment(); }

// skipped for brevity

%%
void comment(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = scanner->input()) != 0)
        if (c == '*')
        {
            while ((c = scanner->input()) == '*');

            if (c == '/')
                return;

            if (c == 0)
                break;
        }
    yyerror("unterminated comment");
}
```

and finally parser.yy which looks like the Ansi C yacc grammar with the addition of this at the top

```
%require "3.2"
%language "c++"
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"

%{
extern int yylex();
%}

%define api.token.constructor
%define api.value.type variant
%define parse.assert

...
```

This setup does not compile of course as `FlexLexer` does not have a member called `input()`, however instantiating yyFlexLexer is also not an option as the `input()` function of that class is protected and not usable.
The Flex manual states one must use `yyinput()` when generating C++ code in flex and uses it as a free standing function which is not available for some reason on my setup.
https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_node/flex_19.html

My question is thus: Is it possible, and if so how, to access the default `input()` functionality when also using the C++ option of Flex, without resorting to creating a separate Lexer class that derives from yyFlexLexer?

Comment: This is the [the current flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/).

Comment: The example code doesn't use `yyinput` as a free-standing function; lexer actions are compiled into the implementation of `yyFlexLexer`. But you can't add your own methods to that class, so you have to derive your own lexer class from `yyFlexLexer`, in which case `yyinput` will be available. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: See `%option yyclass`, which somewhat confusingly is mostly documented in the [description of the C++ version of the `yylex()` method](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#index-yylex-_0028C_002b_002b-version_0029).

Comment: @rici I have seen that. Maybe something is escaping me, but the reason I'd like to avoid deriving from `yyFlexLexer` and creating my own Lexer subclass is because I am actually happy with the default behavior of `input()`. I don't mind creating my own lexer subclass, but as of now there is nothing I am missing.

Comment: You're missing the ability to add member functions like `comment()` to the lexer class, where they belong. And therefore you're missing the ability to call member functions like `yyinput()`, other than directly in an action.